# Как сделать корзину php?

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку(кнопку) происходил переход в корзину, куда добавляется выбранный товар(бисквит)?

```
 <?php 
    require 'functions/function.php';
    if (isset($_POST['korzina'])) {
        korzina();
        redirect();
    }
    ?> 

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Учёт заказов для кондитерского цеха</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/frame.css">

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Tahoma, serif;
        }

        a {
            display: block;
            color: #424242;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid white;
            padding: 10px 0;
            margin: 0 0 10px 0;
            background: #fff;
        }

        a:hover {
            background: transparent;
            color: #db7093;
        }
    </style>

    <body style="background:#faebd7">

    <div name="biskvit" value="'.$biskvit['kod_biskvita'].'"> 

        <h1 class="tort" style="color:#db7093" name="nazvanie" value="'.$biskvit['nazvanie'].'">Классический</h1>
        <div style="position:relative;left:100px; top:10px">
            <img left = "100px" right = "100" width = "420" height = "360" src = "/images/Классический.png"> 
            <p class="p1" style="margin-right: 550px; margin-left: 50px">Сладкий белый бисквит, пропитанный фирменным сметанным кремом. Классический десерт в классической форме.</p>
            <p class="p1"style="margin-right: 550px; margin-left: 50px" name="sostav" value="'.$biskvit['sostav'].'">Состав:<br>Яйца, сахар, мука, сметана.</p>
        </div>

        <a href="cart.php?kod_biskvita=<?php echo $biskvit['6']?>" name="korzina" style="margin-right: 250px; margin-left: 650px;   position:relative; top:-580px">
                    В корзину </a>
    </div>


    <div name="biskvit" value="'.$biskvit['kod_biskvita'].'">

        <h1 class="tort1" style="color:#db7093" name="nazvanie" value="'.$biskvit['nazvanie'].'">Перерождённая классика</h1>
        <div style="position:relative;left:100px; top:-130px">
            <img left = "100px" right = "100" width = "420" height = "360" src = "/images/Перерождённая классика.png"> 
            <p class="p1"style="margin-right: 550px; margin-left: 50px">Ароматные медовые коржи, пропитанные сметанным кремом. Декорирован сметанным кремом, шоколадной глазурью и медовой крошкой.</p>
            <p class="p1" style="margin-right: 550px; margin-left: 50px" name="sostav" value="'.$biskvit['sostav'].'">Состав:<br>Яйца, сахар, мука, соль, сметана, мёд, шоколадная глазурь.</p>
        </div>

        <a href="cart.php?kod_biskvita=<?php echo $biskvit['7']?>" name="korzina" style="margin-right: 250px; margin-left: 650px;   position:relative; top:-695px">
                    В корзину </a>
    </div>


    <div name="biskvit" value="'.$biskvit['kod_biskvita'].'"> 

        <h1 class="tort2" style="color:#db7093" name="nazvanie" value="'.$biskvit['nazvanie'].'">Ореховая нежность</h1>
        <div style="position:relative;left:100px; top:-250px">
            <img left = "100px" right = "100" width = "420" height = "360" src = "/images/Ореховый.png"> 
            <p class="p1"style="margin-right: 550px; margin-left: 80px">Бисквит пропитанный сахарным сиропом и нежным кремом. Декорирован золотистым арахисом, кремовыми пампушками и жареной бисквитной крошкой.</p>
            <p class="p1"style="margin-right: 550px; margin-left: 80px" name="sostav" value="'.$biskvit['sostav'].'">Состав:<br>Яйца, сахарная пудра, сахар, миндальная мука, арахис жаренный, соль, сливочное масло.</p>
        </div>

        <a href="cart.php?kod_biskvita=<?php echo $biskvit['8']?>" name="korzina" style="margin-right: 250px; margin-left: 650px;   position:relative; top:-860px">
                    В корзину </a>
    </div>


    <div name="biskvit" value="'.$biskvit['kod_biskvita'].'"> 
        <h1 class="tort3" style="color:#db7093" name="nazvanie" value="'.$biskvit['nazvanie'].'">Слабость королевы</h1>
        <div style="position:relative;left:100px; top:-350px">
            <img left = "100px" right = "100" width = "460" height = "360" src = "/images/Слабость королевы.png"> 
            <p class="p1"style="margin-right: 550px; margin-left: 100px">Сладкий бисквит, пропитанный кремом. Оформлен ароматной клубникой, фруктовым желе и обожжённым белковым кремом с тонким карамельным ароматом.</p>
            <p class="p1"style="margin-right: 550px; margin-left: 100px" name="sostav" value="'.$biskvit['sostav'].'">Состав:<br>Яйца, сахар, мука, сливочное масло, экстракт ванили, цедра 1 лимона, взбитые сливки и клубника — для украшения.</p>
        </div>

        <a href="cart.php?kod_biskvita=<?php echo $biskvit['9']?>" name="korzina" style="margin-right: 250px; margin-left: 650px;   position:relative; top:-1010px">
                    В корзину </a>
    </div>


    <div name="biskvit" value="'.$biskvit['kod_biskvita'].'">
        <h1 class="tort4" style="color:#db7093" name="nazvanie" value="'.$biskvit['nazvanie'].'">Сметанный</h1>
        <div style="position:relative;left:100px; top:-430px">
            <img left = "100px" right = "100" width = "460" height = "360" src = "/images/Сметанный.png"> 
            <p class="p1"style="margin-right: 550px; margin-left: 110px">Сметанный шоколадный бисквит, пропитанный сахарным сиропом и сливочным сметанный кремом. Оформлен сливочным кремом и шоколадной глазурью.</p>
            <p class="p1"style="margin-right: 550px; margin-left: 110px" name="sostav" value="'.$biskvit['sostav'].'">Состав:<br>Яйца, сахар, мука, сметана, шоколад.</p>
        </div>

        <a href="cart.php?kod_biskvita=<?php echo $biskvit['10']?>" name="korzina" style="margin-right: 250px; margin-left: 650px;   position:relative; top:-1070px">
                    В корзину </a>
    </div>


    <div name="biskvit" value="'.$biskvit['kod_biskvita'].'">
        <h1 class="tort5" style="color:#db7093" name="nazvanie" value="'.$biskvit['nazvanie'].'">Черепаха</h1>
        <div style="position:relative;left:100px; top:-490px">
            <img left = "100px" right = "100" width = "460" height = "360" src = "/images/Черепаха.png"> 
            <p class="p1"style="margin-right: 550px; margin-left: 120px">Бисквитный торт, пропитанный сметанным кремом. Оформлен шоколадным покрытием и белковым кремом, декорирован под черепаху.</p>
            <p class="p1"style="margin-right: 550px; margin-left: 120px" name="sostav" value="'.$biskvit['sostav'].'">Состав:<br>Яйцо куриное, сахар, мука пшеничная х/п в/с, сливки на растительной основе, сметана, гель шоколадный, шоколадная глазурь, какао-порошок.</p>
        </div>

        <a href="cart.php?kod_biskvita=<?php echo $biskvit['11']?>" name="korzina" style="margin-right: 250px; margin-left: 650px;   position:relative; top:-1144px">
                    В корзину </a>
    </div>


    </body>
```

Таблица biskvit в базе данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: php уже в корзине)))

Comment: У вас уже есть в корзине php код обрабатывающий добавление в корзину? Просто у вас в ссылках, скорее всего не передаётся код товара наверно нужно так cart.php?kod_biskvita=<?=$biskvit['kod_biskvita']?> (или так cart.php?kod_biskvita=7, cart.php?kod_biskvita=8 ...) , да и неизвестно что у вас в $biskvit - может вообще ничего нет, не видно что бы по коду он менялся.

Answer (score -1):

Вам нужно хранить где то содержимое корзины, это может быть база данных или сессия или куки например (с чем вам проще работать, думаю сессии нормальный вариант будет), т.е. за каждым пользователем числится корзина (можно хранить товар, выбранное количество).

При переходе на страницу корзины, у вас отображается весь список товаров которые выбрал текущий пользователь (можно добавить информацию что есть в наличии а что закончилось).
На странице товара делаете кнопку добавить в корзину, если по вашей логики то “добавить и перейти в корзину” в урле кнопки делаете параметр говорящий что идёт добавление в корзину товара и уникальный код товара (артикул, или id, например ?addProduct=12345).

Если кнопка нажата то происходит переход на страницу корзины. В начале кода страницы корзины  проверяется есть ли в урле addProduct если есть то добавляете в то место где хранятся все товары добавленные этим пользователем новый товар, далее можно сделать редирект на страницу корзины уже без этого параметра (что бы в итоге урл был красивый без лишних параметров), в итоге на странице у вас появляется список всего что добавлено в корзину (эта механика уже сделана на шагах выше).